# Python: comparar dos archivos y exportarlo

Tags: python

Buscando por la web he conseguido mostrar las diferencias entre dos archivos de texto en uno nuevo, con el siguiente código:

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as file1:
    with open('file2.txt', 'r') as file2:
        difference = set(file1).difference(file2)

with open('diff.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    for line in difference:
        file_out.write(line)
```

El problema está en que me exporta las diferencias con líneas ordenadas alfabéticamente. Por ej:

file1.txt:

```
hola
casa
televisor
sillón
bebida
```

file2.txt:

```
hola
casa
```

diff.txt

```
bebida
sillón
televisor
```

¿Como hago para que en diff.txt no queden las lineas ordenadas alfabéticamente?

Comment: Como las quieres ordenar?

Comment: Sin orden. Es decir: televisor, sillón, bebida.

Comment: No entendi... Cual es el problema? Comparar 2 archivos? Especificar un critério para ordenar valores? No está claro que es lo que necesitas.

Comment: Es cierto. Bueno, generalmente el file1 siempre tendrá más texto que el file2. Ambos son logs de conversaciones. El file1 es el más reciente. Es por eso que necesito sin orden alfabético. Si mantiene orden alfabético la conversación no se entiende.

Comment: Te sugiero edites tu pregunta para que sea mas claro lo que necesitas. Tambien aprovecha y busca sobre la funcion `sorted()` con el parametro `key`

Comment: Tomas la diferencia sería siempre de un archivo frente al otro, es decir te interesan ver las líneas de 1 que no están en 2, pero si hay líneas en 2 que no están en 1 no te interesan. Esto es en realidad lo que hace tu código actual (al margen de que los conjuntos carecen de orden) pero no se si esto es lo que quieres.

Comment: @FJSevilla como tú mencionas. Deseo ver las líneas del file1 que no están en el file2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que los conjuntos no mantienen el orden entre sus elementos, de hecho la salida no es en orden alfabético, no tiene orden directamente. Si ejecutas el script repetidas veces obtendrás diferentes salidas. Cualquier supuesto orden en conjuntos o diccionarios (como ocurre en Python 3.6) debe considerarse hasta el momento solo un efecto colateral de la implementación.

La pena es que la intersección de conjuntos es un método muy eficiente para encontrar las diferencias entre dos conjuntos de datos, dado que las búsquedas en tablas hash tienen complejidad `O(1)` de media, `O(n)` en el peor de los casos.

Dado que buscas las filas de file1.txt que no están en file2.txt pero no a la inversa, puedes seguir usando un conjunto para almacenar las líneas de file2.txt e iterar en orden sobre file1.txt comprobando si la línea existe o no en el conjunto de file2.txt mediante `in`:

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as file1:
    with open('file2.txt', 'r') as file2:
        with open ("output.txt", "w") as out_file:
            f2_lines = set(file2)
            for line in file1:
                if line not in f2_lines:
                    out_file.write(line)
```

La salida para tu ejemplo sería siempre:

> televisor
>   sillón
>   bebida

Ahora bien, si existe una línea repetida  en file1 esta aparecerá también repetida las mismas veces en el fichero de salida. Si no quieres esto puedes añadir la línea al conjunto cuando es encontrada la primera vez:

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as file1:
    with open('file2.txt', 'r') as file2:
        with open ("output.txt", "w") as out_file:
            f2_lines = set(file2)
            for line in file1:
                if line not in f2_lines:
                    out_file.write(line)
                    f2_lines.add(line)
```

Para el siguiente contenido de `file1.txt`:

> hola
>   casa
>   televisor
>   bebida
>   sillón
>   bebida

El primer código nos retornará:

> televisor
>   bebida
>   sillón
>   bebida

y este último:

> televisor
>   bebida
>   sillón

---

> **ADVERTENCIA**: tanto el código original de la pregunta como el anterior de esta respuesta comparan las filas crudas, es decir incluyendo el carácter de nueva línea. Esto es importante, porque si la última línea de los ficheros no acabara con carácter de nueva línea o los ficheros usaran distinto carácter de nueva línea (CR+LF. LF, CR, ...) la comparación fallaría. En estos casos, se puede recurrir a aplicar `str.rstrip` sobre cada fila o corregir el problema en los ficheros previamente a la comparación, etc.

Si tus archivos  tienen **exactamente** el mismo contendido hasta el final de fichero2.txt y solo varían en que file1.txt tiene lineas nuevas que no fueron añadidas a file2.txt tal y como tu ejemplo muestra, entonces podemos jugar con el cursor en vez de cargar datos en memoria:

```
import shutil

with open('file1.txt', 'r') as file1:
    with open('file2.txt', 'r') as file2:
        with open ("output.txt", "w") as out_file:
            file2.seek(0, 2)                      # cursor de file2 al final del fichero  
            file1.seek(file2.tell())              # Cursor de file1 en la posición del de file2
            shutil.copyfileobj(file1, out_file)   # Copiamos file1 hasta el final
```

La salida esperada es la misma que la del primer código, no omite posibles duplicados. Si file1.txt es igual o menor en tamaño que file2.txt el fichero de salida quedará vacío.

Comment: Sinceramente es un gusto recibir un comentario tan bien detallado. Funciona fenomenal, gracias!. El código que necesitaba era el último.

Comment: Por alguna razón en algunos casos output.txt se come las primeras dos letras. Por ejemplo con la palabra HOLA queda LA.

Comment: La razón es porque en ciertos casos ambos files (file1 y file2), tienen dos saltos de lineas vacíos. Si dejo file2 sin salto de linea, no omite las primeras dos letras. ¿Como detectar y solucionar este problema?

Comment: Aún no logro detectar en que momento omite las primeras dos letras... alguna sugerencia @FJSevilla?

Comment: @tomillo perdona se me había pasado tu comentario anterior. El último código en realidad no tiene en cuenta el contenido en sí, solo el número de bytes. Para que ocurra lo que mencionas deben existir dos bytes (en el caso de estar hablando de ASCII) en file2 que no fueron agregados a file1 en el mismo punto, lo cual causa que se "coma" dos bytes de este último. Esto causa que el requisito de que ambos archivos sean idénticos (e idénticos quiere decir mismo número de bytes, no mismo valor de estos) hasta el final de file2 no se cumpla.

Comment: En teoría todo lo que hay en file2 debe estar exactamente igual en file1 (solo que file1 continuó donde file2 lo dejó), si esto no se cumple (por ejemplo se usa distinta codificación en ambos archivos que cause diferencias en el número de bytes para codificar un carácter dado) esta idea falla. Podría solucionarse pero sería necesario saber bajo que condiciones deterministas ocurre que lo que comentas.

Comment: Gracias @FJSevilla. La verdad que no sé cuando falla. Por momentos funciona falla y cuando intento nuevamente, funciona bien.

Comment: file1 y file2 los estoy manejando en utf-8